# Display contents of Textfile data to ListView in C#

Tags: c#, forms, listview, text-files

I have a listview in my form.

In my text file I have this:

---

24-7-2017:13:44:40;x;0.0078;y;-0.0147;z;0.9879;

24-7-2017:13:44:41;x;0.0069;y;-0.0069;z;1.0104;

---

**24-7-2017:13:44:40;** represents the time where I want to put in the first column of the listview

**x;0.0078;y;-0.0147;z;0.9879;** is where I want to create three columns to put the X,Y,Z in the each column and the data in the respective column

the next line will then be in row 2 in their respective column

they are separated by ";"

How I go about displaying it in the listview?

Comment: Read the file with `File.ReadAllLines`, separate the lines with `Split`, save them in an `ObservableCollection` and bind this Collection to your ListView. Please share, what you have tried for more information.

Comment: @azrin Which form is this WPF or WIndows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the new tested answer with the solution.

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //read the file
            System.IO.StreamReader file =
                           new System.IO.StreamReader("yourFileName.txt");

            //set list view in details mode
            listView1.View = View.Details;

            //Set columns in listview
            listView1.Columns.Add("Date Time");
            listView1.Columns.Add("X");
            listView1.Columns.Add("Y");
            listView1.Columns.Add("Z");
            string line = "";
            //read text file line by line.     
            while (( line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                var itemMC = new ListViewItem(new[] { line.ToString().Split(';')[0].ToString(), line.ToString().Split(';')[2].ToString(), 
                    line.ToString().Split(';')[4].ToString(), line.ToString().Split(';')[6].ToString() });
                listView1.Items.Add(itemMC);

            }
            file.Close();
        }
```

Here is the output(from the given data in question) :

[image]

Comment: Stack overflow was creating problem in submitting my edit. thats why, it took time.

Comment: @MongZhu, Right point, I added a listview item and added to list view. Now it should compile.

Comment: Updated the answer, please check is there any problem now. I have tested this in my machine this time.

Comment: now you have a working example! even with an image, great answer! +1

Comment: @AbdurRahim Hi! Your response has been significant for me! Thank you! Gladly appreciated!

Comment: A bit outdated, but you spliting each line of text file 4 times. Also `System.IO.StreamReader.ReadLine()` is already a string, no need to `.ToString()` call. You should `var splits = line.Split(';');` before creating new `ListViewItem`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
        System.Windows.Forms.ListView listView = new System.Windows.Forms.ListView();
        DateTime = ((System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader)(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader()));
        X = ((System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader)(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader()));
        Y = ((System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader)(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader()));
        Z = ((System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader)(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader()));
        SuspendLayout();

        listView.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader[] {
        DateTime,
        X,
        Y,
        Z});
        listView.GridLines = true;
        listView.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details;
        DateTime.Text = "DateTime";
        X.Text = "X";
        Y.Text = "Y";
        Z.Text = "Z";
        this.Controls.Add(this.listView);

        StreamReader file = new StreamReader("filepath");

        string sLine;
        while ((sLine = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] sarr= sLine.Split(';');
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(sarr[0]);
            sb[sarr[0].IndexOf(':')] = ' ';
            sarr[0] = sb.ToString().Replace(':', '.');

            string[] sData = { sarr[0], sarr[2], sarr[4], sarr[6] };

            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(sData);

            listView.Items.Add(item);
        }
```

after this you can add your first data into listView and then do for remain the same. And make sure your listView view property set to Details.

output:

[image]

Comment: OP asked also for the display in the ListView in 3 different columns. Your answer doesn't adress this part of the question.

Comment: @MongZhu now ok?

Comment: this displays the data only in one row, and the x, y, and z values are missing

Comment: @MongZhu [Everything shows on list](http://oi63.tinypic.com/25a8ait.jpg)

Comment: your answer is misleading, When taking only the code you posted, OP will never get the result that is depicted by the image that you have posted. Where do the columns come from? where do the headers of the columns come from? What does OP else (that you have not mentioned) have to do to reach that result?